# Get variable from Zenity list generated from .csv file

Tags: bash, zenity, csv

I'm trying to get the value from `zenity` list. But it doesn't work. Some help would be nice :)

If I remove the `ans=$` I get the value from `zenity` in terminal like this:

```
10.33.54.13|10.33.54.13
```

But I don't know how to make a variable from terminal output.

- data.csv:

  ```
  192.168.10.1;switch0;255.255.255.0;192.168.1
  192.168.10.2;switch1;255.255.255.0;192.168.1
  192.168.10.3;switc2;255.255.255.0;192.168.1
  ```
- Code:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  INPUT=data.csv
  OLDIFS=$IFS
  IFS=";"
  while read IP hostname subnetmask gateway
  do
  echo -e "$IP"

  done < $INPUT|ans=$(zenity --list  --text "Choose witch IP-address you want to connect to " --column "Choose")
  echo "You chose: $ans"
  ```

Comment: FYI the duplicated output (`10.33.54.13|10.33.54.13` in place of `10.33.54.13`) may be due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zenity/+bug/1267788)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sylvain and @kos ! Both of your answares solved the problem! Sylvain pointed out what was wrong with my code and Kos showed me a better way to code it :) 

In order to get rid of "|repeat":   
IFS="|";string=$ans;set $string; CleanAns=$1 ; IFS=$OLDIFS              
echo "You chose: $CleanAns"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code didn't work because you have to capture the whole while loop in the `ans` variable.

Try the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=data.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=";"
ans=$(while read IP hostname subnetmask gateway
do
echo -e "$IP"

done <$INPUT|zenity --list  --text "Choose witch IP-address you want to connect to " --column "Choose")
echo "You chose: $ans"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just want something like this; it will store the selection in a `$var` variable:

```bsh
var="$(awk -F ';' '{print $1}' data.csv | zenity --list --text "Choose witch IP-address you want to connect to " --column "Choose" 2>/dev/null)"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice answer =).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to separate the construction of the input list from the running of the zenity command, perhaps using a bash array e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

infile="data.csv"

declare -a iplist

while IFS=\; read -r IP hostname subnetmask gateway; do 
  iplist+=("$IP")
done < "$infile"

ans="$(zenity --list \
              --text "Choose which IP-address you want to connect to " \
              --column "Choose" "${iplist[@]}")"

echo "You chose: $ans"
```

Also note that you don't need to save and restore `IFS` since you can define the custom `IFS=\;` on the `read` command line.